# How can my model for a compound angular arm be adjusted to account for a special case?

Tags: calculus

I'm creating a robot.  More specifically, I'm creating a robotic arm that can pick up objects and place them accurately in egg-carton slots.  This is for the Science Olympiad(I'm a high school student).  I feel it would be ineffective to try to explain my robot through text, so [here's a LaTex document(with diagrams and my current model) to help explain it](https://github.com/jakewhitton/robotarm/blob/master/theory/VelocityMapping.pdf).

Essentially, my robot is two lengths of material on a flat plane.  There is a joint fixed in space on which the first length is placed.  Then, a second joint it fixed onto the end of that length, and the second length is fixed onto that joint.

The angle which the first length makes with the horizontal is referred to as $\alpha$.  The angle which the second length makes with the horizontal is referred to as $\beta$.

At the end of the second length, there is a particle that is moving with a Cartesian velocity $\vec{v}=\langle\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt}\rangle$.

You have the knowledge of the current values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  You also have the ability to set the current values of $\frac{d\alpha}{dt}$ and $\frac{d\beta}{dt}$.

We define the compound angular-velocity vector as $\vec{\omega}=\langle\frac{d\alpha}{dt},\frac{d\beta}{dt}\rangle$

At the end of my solution, I result in the following.

$
\vec{\omega}(\alpha,\beta,\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt})=\bigg\langle-\frac{1}{\ell_1sin(\alpha)}\bigg[\frac{dx}{dy} + sin(\beta)\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}sin(\alpha) + \frac{dx}{dt}cos(\alpha)}{sin(\alpha)cos(\beta) -cos(\alpha)sin(\beta)}\bigg],\frac{1}{\ell_2}\bigg[\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}sin(\alpha) + \frac{dx}{dt}cos(\alpha)}{sin(\alpha)cos(\beta) -cos(\alpha)sin(\beta)}\bigg]\bigg\rangle
$

I'm pretty happy with this solution.  However, there are some times when the model breaks down.  The most important one, in my eyes, is the case when $\alpha$=$\beta$.

If $\alpha=\beta$, then $sin(\alpha)cos(\beta) -cos(\alpha)sin(\beta)=0$.  That turns out to be a problem, because that motif is in the denominator of both $\frac{d\beta}{dt}$ and $\frac{d\beta}{dt}$.  It makes intuitive sense, too.  I give the following example in the paper.

Imagine that $\alpha=\beta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\vec{v}=\langle1,1\rangle$.  It is clear that there ought to be no vector $\vec{\omega}$, since you are trying to push the particle directly outside of the locus of points the compound arm can inhabit.  That motif in the denominator is a safe-guard against this.

However, imagine a similar kind of situation.  In this case, $\alpha=\beta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ like before, but $\vec{v}=\langle0,-1\rangle$.

In this case, you're attempting to push the particle in such a way that it stays in the locus of points the arm can inhabit.  My intuition tells me there should be some well-defined value of $\vec{\omega}$ for this situation, but because $\alpha=\beta$, my model fails.

Now, I could just implement some sketchy solution to this problem in my code.  I just wanted to check with you all if there was a more elegant solution.

What do you think?  Is there some kind of way that I can get a meaningful result from the cases when $\alpha=\beta$?  Perhaps a kind of piecewise function?

I appreciate the help. :)